# Lambda Expression closure function not working

Tags: c++, lambda

I want to confirm the lambda expression and converted closure by compiler and tried to write the following:

```
//this example demonstrate lambda function in c++

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Sum
{
    int mySum;
    Sum(){}
    Sum(int s):mySum(s){}

    void operator()(int x){
        mySum += x;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vector<int> v { 3, 4, 2, 1, 56, 2, 4, 65, 2, 9, 8, 5, 7 };

     auto sum = 0;
     //for_each(begin(v), end(v), [&mySum = sum](int x){ mySum += x;});
     for_each(begin(v), end(v), Sum());
     cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the above lambda closure is not working. If I remove the default constructor then compiler gives error, If I have this then the result is still 0.

What is going wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure which part of this code you are referring to. Commented out line (lambda) works just fine in C++14. Manually written functor (Sum) works fine too, except you throwing its result away.

Comment: Manually written functor Sum is not giving the correct result of 168 it prints 0

Comment: The Sum functor presumably the conversion of lambda expression by compiler (commented) if I have written correctly.

Comment: You are passing a reference to `sum` in the lambda, but you are not doing anything like that with Sum. So there is an anonymous instance of Sum which does its job, collects 168 into its own local variable `mySum` which is then destroyed together with the functor instance. And then you are printing 0 from `sum` variable (which is not connected to that functor in any way so why would you expect anything different?)

Comment: How does the for_each associate with the local variable `sum`? You are creating a temp object which gets lost after execution of for_each

Comment: You are printing the value of `main`'s local variable `sum`, not the member `mySum` from `struct Sum`. That's why you get 0 instead of 168

Comment: What changes are required to get the same functionality by functor as provided by lambda expression?

Comment: Works fine for me with a minor change. http://ideone.com/nXJB5G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much cleaner would be:

```
vector<int> v { 3, 4, 2, 1, 56, 2, 4, 65, 2, 9, 8, 5, 7 };
auto sum = for_each(begin(v), end(v), Sum()).mySum;
cout << sum << endl;
```

Based on op's comment:

> What changes are required to get the same functionality by functor as
>   provided by lambda expression?

The equivalent code of the lambda would be:

```
struct Sum
{
    int *mySum;
    Sum(){}
    Sum(int *s):mySum(s){}

    void operator()(int x){
        *mySum += x;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vector<int> v { 3, 4, 2, 1, 56, 2, 4, 65, 2, 9, 8, 5, 7 };

     auto sum = 0;
     for_each(begin(v), end(v), Sum(&sum));
     cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a temporary Sum object, passing it to for_each and throwing it away.  Meanwhile, an unrelated int variable called sum is not modified.  In addition, the UnaryFunction taken by std::for_each is by value, so the Sum object it modifies will be temporary anyway.

The lambda captures the closure variables as members, and if they're specified to be references, then they reference things visible in the outside scope regardless of whether the lambda itself is a copy.  You could emulate what lambda does like this:

```
//this example demonstrate lambda function in c++

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Sum
{
    int mySum;
    Sum(){}
    Sum(int s):mySum(s){}

    void operator()(int x){
        mySum += x;
    }
};

// Incorporates a reference to a UnaryFunction so it can be passed by
// reference.
template <class A, class T>
struct LambdaWrapper {
    LambdaWrapper(T &t) :t(t) { }
    void operator () (A a) { return t(a); }
    T &t;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vector<int> v { 3, 4, 2, 1, 56, 2, 4, 65, 2, 9, 8, 5, 7 };

     auto sum = Sum(0);
     //for_each(begin(v), end(v), [&mySum = sum](int x){ mySum += x;});
     //for_each(begin(v), end(v), LambdaWrapper<int,Sum>(sum)); // <-- this would be fine
     for_each(begin(v), end(v), [&sum](int x) { sum(x) }); // <-- also fine
     cout << sum.mySum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int& mySum; Sum(int& s) : mySum(s) {}` is easier than wrapper and works just as well. Also maps better to the original lambda (anonymous temporary instance which references a local variable).

Comment: @AndreyTurkin Thanks it works in a lot cleaner way because of your suggestion of using `int& mySum`.